# NestJS TypeOrm dynamically connect to multiple DB

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I'm building an API that is meant to query from multiple databases, all of these databases are isolated instances of the same data structure, so the idea is for the request to contain to which database to point. The amount of databases is dynamic. Is there a way for a module to set up a different amount of databases when starting up?

I've tried to use typeorm and connect to the specific db when asked but adds some time to the request, so I wanted to know if a way to have them all exists